Compatibility problem or a hardware problem when my computer wakes from sleep
I have a compatibility problem or a hardware problem when my computer wakes from sleep.
My computer turns off about 2 out of 10 times when trying to wake it up from sleep by pressing the physical power button. Moving the mouse or pressing the keyboard never woke up the computer.
The motherboard is MSI PRO B760M-A DDR4 II (MS-7D99).
How can I check all of this to know if i can fix this problem?
I'm using the latest Ubuntu that is fully updated.
When I tried to install Linux Mint, the OS didn't boot up at all.
